# Update AWS ECR for every stable release in docker Hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub, amazon-ecr

I have an docker public image, Now for some reason we had to shift it to AWS ECR,Now I am able to transfer the image to ECR from docker hub, but how to make sure that all the stable release in dockerhub will be pushed to AWS ECR, I want my ECR repo update with latest dockerhub image all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider building and publishing your Docker image through [GitHub](https://github.com/) and its CI (Continuous Integration) [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) option.

That way, you can, in your [GitHub workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/configuring-a-workflow), chain:

- [Publish-Docker-Github-Action](https://github.com/elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action): Publishes docker containers to DockerHub
- [appleboy/docker-ecr-action](https://github.com/appleboy/docker-ecr-action): Uploads Docker Image to Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR).

Each time you are publishing a new version of your image, it would also be available in ECR.

Comment: Are we sure GitHub is being used in this workflow? I do not see it referenced in the question.

Comment: @pygeek I agree but my point is: it is *really* easy to use GitHub and build/update and publish one's own public image through its versioned (in GitHub) Dockerfile and a couple of GitHub Actions.

Comment: It may be better to point the author of the question towards Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment and note your specific implementation as an example.

Comment: @pygeek Sure, let us all wait for the OP's feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Using Docker Registry Sync tool, Dregsy -> https://github.com/xelalexv/dregsy